# Casting IllegalArgumentException for this program

Tags: java

So I am doing a code that converts a string to an array. What is left is basically is to make the code throw the exception IllegalArgumentException
for the last 4 strings you put into the str2ia method.

I can successfully get the code to crash or stay on an infinite loop when trying to make this happen.

And honestly I am sure there is something obvious that I can't see

```
import java.util.Arrays;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class String2intArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("6,8 ,9 , 10")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("1002")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia(", 2")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("Ett,Två")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString((str2ia("1,,2"))));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2ia("1 , 2 ,")));


}
public static int[] str2ia(String s) {
    int arraylengt = 0;
    int arrayindex = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(s).useDelimiter(" *, *");
    if(s.length() == 0)
    {
        int[] emptyArray = {};
        System.out.print("empty array ");
        return emptyArray;
    }
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            int nextInt = scan.nextInt();

            arraylengt ++;
        } else {
            // discard next token
            scan.next();

        }
    }

     int[] intArray = new int[arraylengt];

    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(s).useDelimiter(" *, *");
    try {
        while (scan2.hasNext()) {
            if (scan2.hasNextInt()) {
                intArray[arrayindex] = scan2.nextInt();
                arrayindex++;

            } else {
                // discard next token
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad input");
            }

            }}
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.print("Bad input");
            int[] emptyArray = {};
            return emptyArray;

        }

    {

    return intArray;

           }

          }
             }
```

Comment: `throw` IllegalArgumentException  exception after `scan2.next()` .

Comment: You need to `throw` an exception. It won't throw itself. Like this: `throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");`. Why does your title contain "*Casting*", what has casting to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `hasNextInt()` method. It checks if next token is allowed.
In case it is not allowed you just discard it. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextint.htm

`IllegalArgumentException` is not thrown anywhere from this code. `nextInt()` method doesn't throw it (however it does throw other exceptions): https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm

You should explicitly create an exception in here:

```
} else {
    // discard next token
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad input");
}
```

Comment: Ah of course so obvious, thanks but Now I have problems with the output for the forth output and final output printing out [2] and [1,2], do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest an alternative, much simpler implementation? It throws the `IllegalArgumentException` without you having to do anything.

```
private static Integer[] str2ia(String s) {
    return Arrays.asList(s.split(","))
            .stream()
            .map(String::trim)
            .map(Integer::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .toArray(new Integer[]{});
}
```

See https://bpaste.net/show/e3956354cf1a for this function together with code testing it.

Comment: You need to filter out empty string inside an string of numbers

Comment: @kishorborate If there is an empty string where a number should be, a `NumberFormatException` is thrown as expected. See the question: "make the code throw the exception IllegalArgumentException for the last 4 strings"

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Integer> str2ia(String inputString){
  if (inputString.trim().length() == 0) return new ArrayList<>();
  return Arrays.asList(inputString.trim().split(",")).stream()
    .filter(str -> str.trim().length() > 0)
    .map(str -> Integer.parseInt(str.trim()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Update:** Removed catching `NumberFormatException` as suggested.

Comment: A `NumberFormatException` *is* an `IllegalArgumentException`. Just let it be thrown, no need to catch it.

Comment: Does your code throw an `IllegalArgumentException` for the input `"1,,2"` as requested?